# a number's whole part and fraction part's name in English

Tags: numbers, mathematics

I'm not sure if I need to ask this in the math site or here. I'm actually a developer and I searched many websites to find out what the whole and fraction part of a number is called in English (naming variables) and I couldn't find it so I thought I might ask it here.

For example the number **4.17**, what the integer part(**4**) and the fraction part(**17**) are called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already used the correct terminology: *integer/integral part* and *fractional part*.

> The **fractional part** or **decimal part** of a non‐negative real number x {\displaystyle x} x is the excess beyond that number's integer part.

[Fractional part - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part)

You also might see *noninteger part*, as in:

> **Fractional part**
>
> The function frac(x) giving the fractional (noninteger) part of a real number x.

Weisstein, Eric W. "Fractional Part." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalPart.html

Comment: so I'm going to go with **integer** and **fraction** right? (I don't want to use decimal as it is a meaningful keyword in the language I use)

Comment: thanks a lot Juhasz